# what is best drawing tool for asp.net/.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, drawing

I want to draw a tree on the screen where edges and nodes both have labels, user can zoom on the tree and users can change the locations of objects. In java there is a good tool named "JHotDraw". Is there anything like that for .net or / asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use javascript to render on a browser.

Take a look at the library [TheJit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html).

Comment: i started to work on http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/ before your answer, this work fine for now. However TheJit looks wonderfull, the next time i will definetely use it.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is a server-side technology. You could use `System.Drawing` namespace (GDI+) to create static graphics from the server side, but... *have you considered using SVG or Canvas?*

The first - SVG - is a client-side markup to render real-time vectorial graphics in a regular HTML page.

Canvas is a client-side, 2D pixel-based rendering also for regular HTML pages.

Depending on your needs, you may choose SVG or Canvas.

Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) has good resources for learning more about both:

- [SVG on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG).
- [Canvas on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas).